# How do you control the types of objects you can add to an XElement?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

Is there a way to create a class that derives from `XElement`, but also control the types of objects that can be added to it?

For example, say I have this...

```
public class HtmlHead : XElement {}
```

But I can't override the `Add()` method because it's down at the `XContainer` level. And even if I was to create a class that derives from `XContainer` I still don't have access to override the `Add()` methods.

Why would I want to do this, you ask?

I want to make sure that if my program *compiles* that it also parses the HTML correctly. Like, you can only add certain elements to an HTML `<head>` tag, so I want to make sure only supported tags can be added.

Surely, you won't be adding an `<anchor>` tag to the `<head>` tag—ya' feel me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the passed name via the constructor.

```
public class HtmlHead : XElement
{
    public HtmlHead(object content) : base("head")
    {
        this.Add(content);
    }

    public HtmlHead(params object[] content) : base("head", content) { }
}
```

When an item is added, change notification is performed or you can create a custom method for adding which everyone should use.

Comment: Of course, you can't check it at compile time - you would need to create custom architecture (which is pretty easy).

Comment: I already have a solution in place like you have above, but it only handles the creation of the object. I think creating a custom method for adding that everyone should use is the road I was going to take on this one. I was just hoping there was a better way. Catching the event is also a solution I considered, but then it wouldn't be caught at compile-time and that's really what I need here.

Hmm... thinking of more solutions...

Comment: As I said, you would need a custom architecture. Like having `HtmlElement` overrides to `Add(Anchor a)`, `Add(Title t)`, ... which would limit the available types and it would be a **compile** check as well. I would presonally not do such a thing (at least not for most html tags) - if programmers do not know HTML, it is pretty bad (educate of fire them) and you can validate later as well. It is (IMHO) too much work for little benefit.

Comment: I understand and respect your point of view, but I have a much bigger goal in mind that I don't want to entirely divulge in this post that I know is not a simple task.